# Make an InfoPath field required/unrequired by view

Tags: infopath

I have a SharePoint 2010 list with multiple views associated with it.  I am using an InfoPath 2010 form for each view and I'm wanting to make certain fields required on one view while not being required on the other.

As an example, I'd like the field Location (single line of text) to be required in the Facility view, but I don't want the same Location field (single line of text) to be required in the Finance view.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a field (either in the main data source or a secondary data source, like an xml file, for example). Using rules, populate that field with the name of the current view. Then create a button to submit the form. Add a rule to run when view field = Facility and Location is blank. Let the rule set a variable (field in a secondary source) that is used to Show/Hide a section with an error message on the Facility view. Create another rule to submit and close the form when the location is filled in.